# DropDown List escape characters

Tags: c#

C# ASP.NET I use a drop down list to show stock index symbols and their names. 
My problem is that some symbols begin with "&" and the list does not display the symbol. I have tried to escape with "&&" , "\" and  "'" but neither work. Please can someone suggest how to display it.

Here is the code; tmpstr1 is the symbol, tmpstr2 is the name, padgap measures the # spaces required to pad the line to consistent length and padsize is a string of that length.

```
//find # pad chars to fill required pad
int padgap = 1 + maxlength - StringLength(tmpstr1[i]) - StringLength(tmpstr[i]);
j = 0;
do
{
     j++;
} while (padsize[j] <= padgap);

string pad1 = new string('.', j);
str = tmpstr1[i] + pad1 + tmpstr2[i];

list1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}",str));
```

Comment: Change tag from `C` to `C#`.

Comment: Have you tried replacing '&' with '&amp;'

Comment: What kind of dropdown list is this? WPF, WinForms, WebForms?

Comment: Replacing '&' with '&amp'  replaces "&ASDV" with "ampASDV" !
The dropdown is an asp:DropDownList

Comment: Are you sure that you are replacing '&' with '&amp;' ? because your comment indicates that you tried replacing '&' with '&amp', which is wrong.

Comment: Mike good catch, but I am afraid that "&ASDV" now becomes "amp;ASDV"

Comment: Mike good catch, but I am afraid that "&ASDV" now becomes "amp;ASDV" Here is my code. I am afraid that I don't see how to send you a screen image, but that is what I am seeing. 

         if (tmpstr1[i].Substring(0, 1) == "&")
                        tmpstr1[i] = "&amp;" + tmpstr1[i].Substring(1, tmpstr1[i].Length - 1);

Answer (score 0):

the drop down list is listing index symbols, a spacer to produce a constant line width, followed by the name of the index. 
Some index symbols begin with '&', others with '@' and other are just alphabetical. 
What was happening was that the list displayed the indexes beginning with '&' or '@' without the special character, making them hard to read.

A solution, which is viable but imperfect, was to repeat the special character at the end of the line! That displays with the character as the first and last character; the resulting indexes are readable, but I have to ignore the last character. That's the best that I have been able to achieve! This is what it looks like

&CRSPSCT.........Crsp US Small Cap Tr Index&